# how to change json in the format Kendo charts require

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

[image: theshot]My chart accepts json in the following format:

```
result=   [
 {
    "duration_hrs": 3,
    "eei_conv":78

 }
]
```

but the format I am getting is like the attached screenshot,i don't know how to change it in the above mentioned format,in my controller im passing it like the following"

```
       public JsonResult powerConverter(string regionalManager)
    {




            _powerConv.turbineName.Add(dt["turbine_name"].ToString());
            _powerConv.duration_hrs.Add(double.Parse(dt["duration_hrs"].ToString()));
            _powerConv.abb_conv.Add(dt["abb_conv"].ToString());
            _powerConv.eei_conv.Add(dt["eei_conv"].ToString());
            _powerConv.leit_drive_conv.Add(dt["leit_drive_conv"].ToString());


      return Json(_powerConv, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

in my view I call it with the following ajax:

```
$.ajax({

     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST",
     url: "@Url.Action("powerConverter","Ranking")",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": tmpString }),
         success: function (result) {
  }
```

My Class Model"

```
public class PowerConverterViewModel
{

    public List<string> turbineName { get; set; }
    public List<double> duration_hrs { get; set; }
    public List<string> eei_conv { get; set; }
    public List<string> abb_conv { get; set; }
    public List<string> leit_drive_conv { get; set; }
    public List<string> m_power_name { get; set; }

    public PowerConverterViewModel()
    {
        turbineName = new List<string>();
        duration_hrs = new List<double>();
        eei_conv = new List<string>();
        abb_conv = new List<string>();
        leit_drive_conv = new List<string>();
        m_power_name = new List<string>();


    }




}
}
```

Comment: What 'screen shot'?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have attached

Comment: Your required json is a collection of objects, which contain properties `duration_hrs` and `eei_conv`. You creating a single object containing 2 collections properties

Comment: what should I do to get the object in that format?because kendo charts does not accept the current format I am getting

Comment: I have no idea what your model and data is - but you need to pass an array of objects, for example `var data = new[] { new { duration_hrs = 3, eei_conv = 78 }, new { duration_hrs = 4, eei_conv = 40 } }; return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my question witth the class I am using as my model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166606/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-papagallo).

Comment: Add properties to _powerConv object related  class and add data to its list